# Trying to avoid loading a large dataset with every .py file run

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, control-flow, try-except

I'm stuck on a simple bit of code.

I want to load the gloVe model (a large dataset of vectors) only if it has not already been loaded; ie, I don't want to wait while it reloads every time I run my .py file (it can take awhile each time). However, every time I run the script, it loads as if it has never been run before.

I'm using Spyder 4 in a conda virtual environment with Python 3.6.10 on Mac.

Here are three things I have tried:

```
# Check if gloVe already loaded. If yes, skip loading again. 
try:
    gloveModel
except NameError:
    # Load gloVe pre-trained vectors. 
    # Each key is a word; each val is a np array of length 50. 
    filename = 'glove_twitter_50d.txt'
    print("gloVe vectors loading . . .")
    foo = open(filename,'r')
    gloveModel = {}
    for line in foo:
        splitLines = line.split()
        word = splitLines[0]
        wordEmbedding = np.array([float(value) for value in splitLines[1:]])
        gloveModel[word] = wordEmbedding
    print(len(gloveModel),"gloVe loaded.")
else:
    print("gloVe already loaded.")
```

And also

```
   # Check if gloVe already loaded. If yes, skip loading again. 
try:
    assert('gloveModel' in locals() or 'gloveModel' in globals())
except AssertionError:
    # Load gloVe pre-trained vectors. 
    # Each key is a word; each val is a np array of length 50. 
    filename = 'glove_twitter_50d.txt'
    print("gloVe vectors loading . . .")
    foo = open(filename,'r')
    gloveModel = {}
    for line in foo:
        splitLines = line.split()
        word = splitLines[0]
        wordEmbedding = np.array([float(value) for value in splitLines[1:]])
        gloveModel[word] = wordEmbedding
    print(len(gloveModel),"gloVe vectors loaded.")
else:
   print("gloVe already loaded.")
```

And then also

```
# Check if gloVe already loaded. If yes, skip loading again. 
try:
    present = 'gloveModel' in locals() or 'gloveModel' in globals()
    if not present:
        raise ValueError
except ValueError:
    # Load gloVe pre-trained vectors. 
    # Each key is a word; each val is a np array of length 50. 
    filename = 'glove_twitter_50d.txt'
    print("gloVe vectors loading . . .")
    foo = open(filename,'r')
    gloveModel = {}
    for line in foo:
        splitLines = line.split()
        word = splitLines[0]
        wordEmbedding = np.array([float(value) for value in splitLines[1:]])
        gloveModel[word] = wordEmbedding
    print(len(gloveModel),"gloVe vectors loaded.")
else:
   print("gloVe already loaded.")
```

Thanks in advance, I appreciate it

Comment: Try putting the dataset in another class module; which is pre-instantiated on import.  When Py sees it’s already imported, it won’t try again.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind please elaborating? I'm still pretty inexperienced with Python. I made a new module named glove_data.py containing a class named Glove.

Then, in my main file I did `from glove_data import Glove`; then tried to only instantiate a new class if the try block failed. 

`try: <br/>
    assert('gloveModel' in locals() or 'gloveModel' in globals()) <br/>
except AssertionError: <br/>
    Glove() <br/>
else: <br/>
   print("gloVe already loaded.")
` 
Sorry for the formatting...

Comment: Nearly there.  At the very bottom of your glove_data module, write: glove_data = Glove().  Then in your main module use: from glove_data import glove_data.  Providing your dataset is an object of the Glove class, the data will be imported into your main module with the glove_data object.

Comment: Perhaps you should cache that file on disk?

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense as written. Every time you run a python script you're starting a new process. There is no way to avoid having to initialize your data structures when starting a new process. You might be able to make the process faster by using the `pickle` module to save the data structure to disk in a highly efficient representation. Then the next time you run your program load the pickled data rather than reconstructing the model the hard way.